# Spam-able button that play sound

Tags: java, android, button, audio

I need help figuring out how to make a button that will play the same sound over and over again without having to wait for the sound to finish playing.

here is my code so far.

```
final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.boosto);


Button button = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button);

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {


            mp.start();

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

**SoundPool**

SoundPool contains a set of source music, the sound source can be from music file in the app or in the file system, .. SoundPool support  play music sources simultaneously.

how to use:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html

```
SoundPool sp = new SoundPool(5, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);

 /** soundId for Later handling of sound pool **/
 int soundId = sp.load(context, R.raw.windows_8_notify, 1); 

 sp.play(soundId, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
```

example:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


   private SoundPool soundPool;

   private AudioManager audioManager;

   // Maximumn sound stream.
   private static final int MAX_STREAMS = 5;

   // Stream type.
   private static final int streamType = AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC;

   private boolean loaded;

   private int soundIdDestroy;
   private int soundIdGun;
   private float volume;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       // AudioManager audio settings for adjusting the volume
       audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);

       // Current volumn Index of particular stream type.
       float currentVolumeIndex = (float) audioManager.getStreamVolume(streamType);

       // Get the maximum volume index for a particular stream type.
       float maxVolumeIndex  = (float) audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(streamType);

       // Volumn (0 --> 1)
       this.volume = currentVolumeIndex / maxVolumeIndex;

       // Suggests an audio stream whose volume should be changed by
       // the hardware volume controls.
       this.setVolumeControlStream(streamType);

       // For Android SDK >= 21
       if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21 ) {

           AudioAttributes audioAttrib = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                   .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_GAME)
                   .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                   .build();

           SoundPool.Builder builder= new SoundPool.Builder();
           builder.setAudioAttributes(audioAttrib).setMaxStreams(MAX_STREAMS);

           this.soundPool = builder.build();
       }
       // for Android SDK < 21
       else {
           // SoundPool(int maxStreams, int streamType, int srcQuality)
           this.soundPool = new SoundPool(MAX_STREAMS, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
       }

       // When Sound Pool load complete.
       this.soundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener() {
           @Override
           public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId, int status) {
               loaded = true;
           }
       });

       // Load sound file (destroy.wav) into SoundPool.
       this.soundIdDestroy = this.soundPool.load(this, R.raw.destroy,1);

       // Load sound file (gun.wav) into SoundPool.
       this.soundIdGun = this.soundPool.load(this, R.raw.gun,1);

   }



   // When users click on the button "Gun"
   public void playSoundGun(View view)  {
     if(loaded)  {
         float leftVolumn = volume;
         float rightVolumn = volume;
         // Play sound of gunfire. Returns the ID of the new stream.
         int streamId = this.soundPool.play(this.soundIdGun,leftVolumn, rightVolumn, 1, 0, 1f);
     }
   }

   // When users click on the button "Destroy"
   public void playSoundDestroy(View view)  {
       if(loaded)  {
           float leftVolumn = volume;
           float rightVolumn = volume;

           // Play sound objects destroyed. Returns the ID of the new stream.
           int streamId = this.soundPool.play(this.soundIdDestroy,leftVolumn, rightVolumn, 1, 0, 1f);
       }
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When playback has already started, calls to `start()` don't have any effect. Use `seekTo()` to reset playback to the beginning.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(mp.isPlaying())
        mp.seekTo(0L, MediaPlayer.SEEK_NEXT_SYNC); // continues playback from millisecond 0
    else
        mp.start();
}
```